# Is it possible to lock all notes, and automatically lock new notes, on Notes app?

Tags: macos, ios, encryption, notes.app

I see that it's possible to password protect specific notes

I wonder if this can be done automatically to new notes so that I don't need to do it every time, if I want encrypted notes

Is it possible to lock all notes, and automatically lock new notes, on Notes app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you can't set all notes to be locked.** But that doesn't mean they're not all encrypted.

If you scroll ALL the way down in Passcode settings (if you have a passcode), you'll see a little line of text that says `Data protection is enabled.`

That means everything on your device is encrypted with your passcode. That's why Apple can't unlock it for you - it's silently encrypted.

Therefore, all your notes (if you have a passcode) are already encrypted. Adding a lock is an extra layer, but you can't add a lock automatically.

If you'd like notes to automatically lock, feel free to send apple some feedback at **[apple.com/feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)**

Comment: i assume you know there is a company from israel that sells the devices that unlocks the locked iphones (pressumably eg to governments eg when police gets your iphone etc) so master password = no password. tell me if i am wrong.